# Получить данные после binding wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Не могу разобраться, как после `Binding` получить данные с заполненных полей. Читал про двусторонний `Binding`, но это не то что мне нужно. Нужно просто получить данные для дальнейшего сохранения в базу данных

```
<ListView Name="lbTodoList" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="0,2">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Name="textmext"
                                           Grid.Column="0"
                                           Text="{Binding vopros}" />
                                <ComboBox Name="combo"
                                          Grid.Column="1"
                                          IsEditable="True"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding otvet}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Comment: Почему двусторонний Binding не то, что вам нужно? И какие конкретно данные вы хотите получить?

Comment: У `ComboBox` надо забиндить `SelectedItem`, это будет выбранный ответ.

Comment: @VladD двусторонний биндинг изменит данные в классе, а мне ничего изменять не нужно. Нужно просто получить Text из TextBlock и выбранное значение из ComboBox. Получить можно либо в массив, либо в какой-нибудь лист

Comment: Получить данные из View можно, считывая руками. Это противоречит MVVM (т. к. VM не должна знать View), но если вы им не пользуетесь, делайте как хотите. Я бы на вашем месте использовал двусторонний `Binding` (а если не хотите модифицировать данные в объекте `A`, то делайте двусторонний Binding к объекту `B`).

Answer (score 1):

У ListView должна быть привязка к коллекции:
`<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"..`

А вот и сама коллекция: 
`public ObservableCollection<T> Items { get; set; }`